How does one use vllm with pytorch 2.2.2 and python 3.11?
Title: How does one use vllm with pytorch 2.2.2 and python 3.11?
I'm trying to use the vllm library with pytorch 2.2.2 and python 3.11. Based on the GitHub issues, it seems vllm 0.4.1 supports python 3.11.
However, I'm running into issues with incompatible pytorch versions when installing vllm. The github issue mentions needing to build from source to use pytorch 2.2, but the pip installed version still uses an older pytorch.
I tried creating a fresh conda environment with python 3.11 and installing vllm:
$ conda create -n vllm_test python=3.11
$ conda activate vllm_test
(vllm_test) $ pip install vllm
...
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
vllm 0.4.1 requires torch==2.1.2, but you have torch 2.2.2 which is incompatible.

I also tried installing pytorch 2.2.2 first and then vllm:
(vllm_test) $ pip install torch==2.2.2
(vllm_test) $ pip install vllm
...
Building wheels for collected packages: vllm
  Building wheel for vllm (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for vllm (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

Can someone clarify what versions of vllm, pytorch and python work together currently? Is there a recommended clean setup to use vllm with the latest pytorch 2.2.2 and python 3.11?
I've tried creating fresh conda environments, but still run into version conflicts. Any guidance on the right installation steps would be much appreciated. Thanks!
ref: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747

PyTorch 2.2.2 is not supported as of vllm 0.4.1. You can build vllm from source with a custom PyTorch version or wait for the next release of vllm as mentioned here.
You can install vllm 0.4.1 with pytorch 2.2.1 as mentioned in the release notes.
I have tested it with the following steps:
conda create -n vllm_test python=3.11 
conda activate vllm_test
pip install torch==2.2.1
pip install vllm


why didn't you do pip install vllm==0.4.1 here?

You can also specify the version since vllm 0.4.1 is the latest version, pip tries to install that by default. Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples
